# Scraping json response using scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

[JSON RESPONSE FROM WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAaKY.png) I am new to python scrapy and json . I am trying to scrape json response from 78751 . But it is showing error . The code i used is

```
import scrapy
import json 
class BlackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'black'
    start_urls = ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/2360/reviews/2.17.2?page=1&pagesize=100&sortby=newest&callback=_content_2360_reviews_2_17_2&_=1499161778751']





    def parse(self, response):
         data = re.findall('(\{.+\})\);', response.body_as_unicode())
         a=json.loads(data[0])

         item = MyItem()
         item["Reviews"] = a["reviews"][4]["review"]           

         return item
```

The error it is showing is 
 ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ljJ.png)

Comment: It looks like your page is returning HTML content not JSON. Checking it via curl got me an html file that says the site is under maintenance.

Comment: It's working here let me add the screenshot of the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you are getting is javascript function with some json in it:

> _content_2360_reviews_2_17_2(\r\n{"some":"json"}]});\r\n

To extract the data from this you can use simple regex solution:

```
import re
import json
data = re.findall('(\{.+\})\);', response.body_as_unicode())
json.loads(data[0])
```

It trasnslates to: select everything between `{}` that ends with `);`

edit: results I'm getting with this:

```
{'platform': None,
 'reviews': [{'createdDate': '2017-07-04',
   'model': 'London',
   'nickname': 'aravind14-92362',
   'rating': 6,
   'review': 'Very bad ',
   'title': 'My WhatsApp no update '}],
 'totalReviews': 569909,
 'version': '2.17.2'}
```

Comment: To add: the format is called "[JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)". It is was often used (before CORS became mainstream) to get around the same-origin policy.

Comment: I am new to it where to add the url of json response with regex.

Comment: @emon I'm sorry, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: why it is showing error when i put item["Reviews"] = a["reviews"][4]["review"]

Comment: @emon, I'm still confused. Check out my edit, I can succesfully get review via `data['reviews'][0]['review']`.

Comment: i have updated the link, what about the other reviews from different users?

Comment: [link](https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/2360/reviews/2.17.2?page=1&pagesize=10&sortby=newest&callback=_content_2360_reviews_2_17_2&_=1499161778751) ,what about other reviews like if i want to iterate